# mvn: command not found for Git Bash but Java and Maven path are ok using CMD

Tags: bash, maven

I try to understand what is the problem for git bash: **mvn: command not found**

I set path in this way:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;export PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_281/bin:/c/Program\ Files/apache-maven-3.8.1/bin
```

I check with cmd Maven and Java and seems to be ok

[image: maven]

Comment: Remote M2_HOME, MAVEN_HOME and add the path to your installation "bin" directory in your `PATH`. After doing so close the command line and reopen it.

Comment: Note that "git bash" is really just a port of bash to Windows. It has nothing to do with Git. Git needs a bash-style shell, so many ports of *Git* for Windows include bash. But this is like buying a cookware set that comes with a free salt-and-pepper-shaker set: the salt-and-pepper-shaker set is not part of the cookware. Don't use the [tag:git] tag for bash questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution by **khmarbaise**

I removed M2_HOME, MAVEN_HOME and I change path in this way

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin;
```

I retype `mvn --version` and works correctly

[image: solution]

Answer (score 1):

In git bash, try

```
echo $PATH
```

check which of the equivalent entries from your windows paths is missing.  Probably $M2_HOME/bin or $MAVEN_HOME/bin.  Add those to your .bashrc (the file that tells git bash how to setup its environment) by adding a line like the following, including whatever seems to be missing:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:${MAVEN_HOME}/bin:${M2_HOME}/bin
```

for changes to reflect, open a new git bash and run your mvn command again in there.

Comment: Usage of MAVEN_HOME and M2_HOME is useless. Remove them. Only add apache-maven-3.6.3/bin directory to PATH. Apart from that the poster has a windows system and not a Linux based system.

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, you're right, I change path in this way `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin;` and after running again `mvn --version` it works correclty `$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.1
Java version: 1.8.0_281, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\j...`